# How can use GitHub project to my current visual studio project

Tags: angularjs, bower

i dont have a lot experience, but i want to try to use [this](https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager). 
I have a MVC project created in visual studio, using AngularJS routing.
I want to integrating to my current project file manager project, can someone explain me how can do it?

How can install bower inside my visual project?

Comment: Installing bower? Just follow the official docs https://bower.io/#install-bower About integrating, try to be more specific, put it working using the directive and go after that.

Comment: i dont get it. Why should install bower from command when i use visual studio? Cannot simply integrating fileManager project with my own project?